# How to get all Unicode characters from specific categories?

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-3, ecmascript-4

How to get, for example..., a code point pattern like `x-y\uxxxx\Uxxxxxxxxx` from the Connector Punctuation (*Pc*) category, for scanning ECMAScript 3/JavaScript identifiers?

#### Original question

I need help for verifying a valid character (code point) of a ECMA-262 ([3º edition](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), 7.6) identifier for a lexical scanner.

**Syntax quote**

> `Identifier` ::
>
> - `IdentifierName` but not `ReservedWord`
>
> `IdentifierName` ::
>
> - `IdentifierStart`
> - `IdentifierName` `IdentifierPart`
> - `IdentifierStart` ::
> - `UnicodeLetter`
> - **$**
> - **_**
> - <s>**\** `UnicodeEscapeSequence`</s> *# no need to check this*
>
> `IdentifierPart` ::
>
> - `IdentifierStart`
> - `UnicodeCombiningMark`
> - `UnicodeDigit`
> - `UnicodeConnectorPunctuation`
>
> `UnicodeLetter` ::
>
> - *any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (**Lu**)”, “Lowercase > letter (**Ll**)”, “Titlecase letter (**Lt**)”,
>     “Modifier letter (**Lm**)”, “Other letter (**Lo**)”, or “Letter number
>     (**Nl**)”.*
>
> `UnicodeCombiningMark` ::
>
> - *any character in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark (**Mn**)” or “Combining spacing mark (**Mc**)”*
>
> `UnicodeDigit` ::
>
> - *any character in the Unicode category “Decimal number (**Nd**)”*
>
> `UnicodeConnectorPunctuation` ::
>
> - *any character in the Unicode category “Connector punctuation (**Pc**)”*

As you can see, it takes any character of certain categories.

I need to have all these possible characters, so my first step was to locate "Connector punctuation" on this Unicode 5.0 [chart](http://unicode.org/Public/5.0.0/charts/CodeCharts.pdf), but 0 matches and I believe I'm doing it the wrong way. So could someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode offers [this tool](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp) for determining sets of characters. It uses regular expressions with property-value pairs enclosed in `[::]`.

For all characters in Unicode 5 you want to do `[:age=5.0:]`.

The rest are "general categories" (gc). So for example `[:age=5.0:]&[:gc=Lu:]` will find all uppercase letters in Unicode 5 (`gc=L` will find all letters in general).

For IdentifierStart you need `[:age=5.0:]&[[:gc=L:][:gc=Nl:]\$_]`. For IdentifierPart you need `[:age=5.0:]&[[:gc=L:][:gc=Nl:][:gc=Mn:][:gc=Mc:][:gc=Nd:][:gc=Pc:]\$_]`.

Unicode also has properties called ID_Start and ID_Continue but they don't include the same characters as your specifications.

[Here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/properties.jsp) is also an overview of all Unicode character properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP. I'm actually using another approach for determining Unicode General Category. I made a tool for converting `UnicodeData.txt` file into very optimal binaries: https://github.com/matheusdiasdesouzads/unicode-general-category/tree/master/data and a library for working with General Categories: https://github.com/matheusdiasdesouzads/unicode-general-category/tree/master/language-specific/javascript-nodejs

```js
let cat = GeneralCategory.from(0x41);
cat.toString(); // 'Lu'
```